# How to use https connection in python?

Tags: python

I have this simple working curl command:

```
curl -k -d X-User=user -d X-Password=password https://12.12.12.21
```

This is my example:

```
import urllib2
opener = urllib2.build_opener()
opener.addheaders = [('X-User', 'user'),('X-Password', 'password')]
rr = opener.open("https://12.12.12.21")
print rr.read()
```

It's not working as i expected ( result: wrong password/user name ), can you help me understand why?

Comment: i just tested it with https://www.google.com and it works like a charm... what where you expecting as output? are you getting any error? can you provide your stacktrace, eventually?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `curl` command is using the `-d` flag which [sends the data using POST](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html), not using headers.

If you meant to use headers then you need to use the `-H` argument:

```
curl -k -H X-User=user -H X-Password=password https://12.12.12.21
```

Here is how to do a POST request in case that is what you need:

```
values = {'X-User' : 'user', 'X-Password' : 'password'}
data = urllib.urlencode(values)
req = urllib2.Request("https://12.12.12.21", data)
rr = urllib2.urlopen(req)
```